# A parabola lemma

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am looking for a previous reference and/or a geometric proof of the following lemma:

Let $P$ be the parabola $y=x^2$. Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be four points on $P$ sorted from left to right, and let $z$ be the point of intersection of the segments $ac$ and $bd$. Define the horizontal distances $p=b_x-a_x$, $q=d_x-c_x$, $r=z_x-b_x$, $s=c_x-z_x$. Then, $p/q=r/s$.

This is easily proven algebraically, but I was wondering whether there is a geometric argument.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to treat P(x,y) as a vector if you want to use geometric arguments? Just wondering, i'm not very good with geometry and vectors.

Comment: True for the other conics also ?

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to prove $\frac {r}{p} = \frac {s}{q}$ .

[image]

In the green shaded region, by intercept theorem, we have $\frac { ZC’}{C’D} = \frac {s}{q}$.

Similarly, in the yellow region, we have $\frac {ZB’}{B’A} = \frac {r}{p}$ .

It remains to show is $B’C’$ parallel $AD$. [A geometric interpretation of the result]

The above must be true because the equality of the said ratios has been proven algebraically.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how you prove that $B'C'$ is parallel to $AD$. Or are you using circular reasoning -- relying on the fact that $r/p=s/q$ in order to conclude that $B'C'$ is parallel to $AD$?

Comment: @GabrielNivasch The approach that I am using is exactly the last part of your comment **but it is not a circular reasoning**. You have mentioned that “This (p/q = r/s) is easily proven algebraically”. In other words, r/p = s/q is also true. Applying intercept theorem twice, we get ZB’ / B’A = ZC’ /C’D. The last result , together with <B’ZC’ = <AZD as common angle, yield ⊿ZB’C’ ~ ⊿ZAD. Thus, BC’ // AD because corresponding angles equal. Of course, proving the 2 lines parallel directly is also possible but I will not start it that way because you have made a claim already.